# Don't Run Unit Tests from Certain Assemblies in TFS 2012 Build Definition

Tags: msbuild, nunit, build-automation

In TFS 2012, we have several build definitions - CIs, Deployments and nightly.

Our CI builds run all of the (n)unit tests from our solution, however, we need to get it to ignore certain tests.

This is because we have some long running integration tests, and these only need to be run nightly.

Things I've tried:

- Using the `TestCategoryAttribute` (from MSTest) and setting the Test Case Filter property try and exclude 'Integration'.
- Using the `CategoryAttribute` (from NUnit) and setting the Test Case Filter property try and exclude 'Integration'.
- A combination of the above.

The tests that need to be ignored are all in separate assemblies with the word IntegrationTests or Integration.Tests in the name.

Thanks,
Kieron

Comment: I'd add xUnit tests also. How to filter those?

Answer (score 10):

I've been using a combination of the MSTest TestCategory attribute on my unit tests, and the Test category filter setting for my build process definition in TFS 2012.

According to the Microsoft MSDN article found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253138.aspx) **you can specify which categories to use by setting the *Test category filter* to**

```
TestCategory=CategoryName
```

According to your original post, you'd need to use the following filter:

```
TestCategory!=Integration
```

and decorate your tests with this attribute:

```
[TestCategory("Integration")]
```

Do this on all of your unit tests that you want ignored during your build. The test lists have been deprecated in Visual Studio, and it took a while to convert everything to the categories, but in the end it's worth it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: They don't explicitly mention it anywhere in documentation, but this syntax works for ANDS TestCategory!=External&TestCategory!=UITest

Comment: That's good for MSTests, but how about NUnit tests? And personally I'm interested in xUnit test filtering also, we have all of the three kinds.

Comment: I'll second xUnit...!

Comment: Note that if you are filtering Test categories in your TFS build definitions you leave out the _TestCategory=_ bit and just specify the CategoryName  by itself e.g. _!Integration_